# Unable to start vagrant due to host networking issues

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I was given a **large** Vagrantfile as part of an inherited project and on doing `vagrant up`, I get the following error:

```
The specified host network collides with a non-hostonly network!
This will cause your specified IP to be inaccessible. Please change
the IP or name of your host only network so that it no longer matches that of
a bridged or non-hostonly network.
```

1. I have made sure no other VMs are running by checking output of `vagrant global-status`.
2. I am not on VPN and
3. I have restarted my machine (Mac laptop).

Yet the error persists.
What to do?

I cannot share the large Vagrantfile but still need to get past this error.
My machine is connected to the Internet using Wi-Fi only, no cable connection.
I am also not very familiar with network-debugging commands.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the IP you assigned to the VM. If the IP collapses with a network range you should change it.

For example, you might be safe using an IP from range `192.0.2.0/24`
If the `192.168.0.0/16` range does not work, you can completely switch to one of the following range

- 10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255
- 172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255

Choosing one or the other will depend of the network configuration of your office.